# Should there be a guideline for naming Identification requests?

Tags: discussion, identification-questions

Lately if been skimming around the questions tagged [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) to see if I could manage to answer some. And noticed that allot of questions either put a whole question in there like [What is this manga with a female protagonist that changes genders and personalities based on the rings she wears?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6887/what-is-this-manga-with-a-female-protagonist-that-changes-genders-and-personalit)   And others just post some really universal name https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/7594/i-cant-remember-the-name-of-this-manga
and it seems the question titles start to go even broader in variety with the latest post being
https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/8190/i-beg-for-help-kind-stranger-identification-request-please
(besides the fact this Identification request definitely should be removed from the title) I was wondering if we maybe should adopt a rule in naming identification-requests

The options I taught of myself if it is deemed necessary would be either.

1. Just use universal naming, https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/7594/i-cant-remember-the-name-of-this-manga
2. A excerpt kinda title  Like [What is this manga with a female protagonist that changes genders and personalities based on the rings she wears?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6887/what-is-this-manga-with-a-female-protagonist-that-changes-genders-and-personalit)

Comment: I'm in favor of the latter. I try to edit them whenever possible (if there's a decent bit of information).

Comment: @Eric Same here, it also makes it look more like a real question instead of something broad/universal.

Comment: Yeah. I'll type a fuller answer and we can get community opinion.

Comment: Related [Questions with the same title](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/695)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given that our ever-so-kind Stack Exchange overlords run a Q&A hub, I think it makes sense for *all posts* to have a question as their title. Identification requests are no exception.

This is actually twofold on identification requests. Consider that the tag is prepended to the title of the post, so it looks something like this:

> identification-request - Requesting an anime identification

Well, duh! The Redundancy Committee of Redundancy approves this.

**I propose that all identification request questions should have their title edited to be phrased as a question containing at least one pertinent detail from the request.**

> identification-request - What is the anime featuring a team of loli basketball players and their coach?

This way, the title is unique, searchable, and can draw eyes from people who might be able to help (who may not be looking at identification requests in general). As members of the community, we can edit questions that do not fulfill this requirement, as it's generally a pretty easy fix. In the case there is not enough information to edit a title in this manner, a comment should be left to the OP (as generally the question isn't clear enough to be considered a good question anyway).